# GKE | Cluster won't provision in any region

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE cluster running in us-central1 with a preemptable node pool.  I have nodes in each zone (us-central1-b,us-central1-c,us-central1-f).  For the last 10 hours, I get the following error for the underlying node vm:

```
Instance '[instance-name]' creation failed: The zone 
'[instance-zone]' 
does not have enough resources available to fulfill 
the request. Try a different zone, or try again 
later.
```

I tried creating new clusters in different regions with different machine types, using HA (multi-zone) settings and I get the same error for every cluster.

I saw an issue on [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/container-engine/18005) and tried with the console, as recommended, and it errors out with a timeout error.

Is anyone else having this problem?  Any idea what I may be dong wrong?

**UPDATES**

- Nov 11

  - I stood up a cluster in us-west2, this was the only one which would work.  I used gcloud command line, it seems the UI was not effective. There was a note similar to this situation, use gcloud not ui, on the Google Cloud Status Dashboard.
  - I tried creating node pools in us-central1 with the gcloud command line, and ui, to no avail.
  - I'm now federating deployments across regions and standing up multi-region ingress.
- Nov. 12

  - Cannot create HA clusters in us-central1; same message as listed above.
  - Reached out via twitter and received a response.
  - Working with the [K8s guide to federation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-federation/cluster/) to see if I can get multi-cluster running.  Most likely going to use [Kelsey Hightowers approach](https://github.com/kelseyhightower/kubernetes-cluster-federation)
  - Only problem, can't spin up clusters to federate.

**Findings**

- Talked with google support, need a $150/mo. package to get a tech person to answer my questions.
- Preemptible instances are not a good option for a primary node pool.  I did this because I'm cheap, it bit me hard.

  - The new architecture is a primary node pool with [committed use](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts) VMs that do not autoscale, and a secondary node pool with preemptible instances for autoscale needs.  The secondary pool will have minimum nodes = 0 and max nodes = 5 (for right now); this cluster is regional so instances are across all zones.
  - Cost for an n1-standard-1 [sustained use](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/sustained-use-discounts) (assuming 24/7) a 30% discount off list.
  - Cost for a 1-year n1-standard-1 [committed use](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts) is about ~37% discount off list.
  - Preemptible instances are re-provisioned every 24hrs., if they are not taken from you when resource needs spike in the region.
  - I believe I fell prey to a resource spike in the us-central1.
- A must-watch for people looking to federate K8s: [Kelsey Hightower - CNCF Keynote | Kubernetes Federation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kwOvOLnFYck)

Comment: I'm also seeing repeated failures to create a kubernetes cluster on us-central1 (ui + command line).

Comment: @AndrewLittle, thank you for the confirmation!

Comment: As your update confirms, it's a known issue; [the Hacker News thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=18428497) is already 250 comments deep

Comment: try with a specific one: `us-east1-d`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel, thank you for this.  Holy cow did that thread blow up quick!

Comment: @Padi, let me give this a shot

Comment: @Padi, I was able to get an HA cluster running in us-east1, thank you.  I have retried all US regions this morning and it seems this was the only successful one so far.  The rest have been attempting instantiation for the past 20 mins, so I expect them to fail.

Comment: @Padi, us-east1 seems to be the only consistent US region for creating clusters.  All other regions have failed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a temporary downtime caused in a service.

Comment: @AhmetAlpBalkan-Google, is there a reference to what caused this issue?  I successfully attempted to spin up an HA cluster in us-central1 and it works.  I'm all for closing this out given it appears to be resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue appears to be resolved as of Nov 13th.